# How do I append to a hyperlink created by a form submission using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, forms

I have a group of drop-downs in a form. Each drop down adds a variable to a URL ie:(?year=2010&position=C) with year and position being different drop-downs.

On submission of this form I am looking to append an additional variable that is not included in the form. ie(&location=/123/abc)

I am looking to accomplish this using jQuery. I am currently appending links on a page, but have no idea how to append to the href created by the form submission. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the beginning of the form

```
<form id="SimpleForm" name="SimpleForm" action="/club/app" method="post">
```

This is the submission button

```
<input type="submit" value="Go">
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how to set the action attribute of your form with the url you're constructing?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can see:

1) create a hidden control called location with the value you require

2) Use jquery to manually construct the querystring and post the form.

I suspect the former will be the easier approach for you.

Answer (score 0):

add a hidden input field for each pair you wanna add:

```
$("#SimpleForm").submit(function(e){
    // for each key/value pair:
    $(this)
        .append($("<input />").attr({"type":"hidden", "name":"keyA"}).val("value 1"))
        .append($("<input />").attr({"type":"hidden", "name":"keyB"}).val("value 2"));

    alert($(this).html());
});
```

see a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/6gHhR/

Answer (score 0):

Would a jquery post work?
You can set the URL cause the action will be on the end of the url.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
or found this article about changing the action wiht jquery.
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/1277764ec2bdc711?pli=1